# Python how to grab certain number of lines after match

Tags: python, printing, lines, text-files

Let's say I have an input text file of the following format:

```
Section1 Heading    Number of lines: n1
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line n1
Maybe some irrelevant lines

Section2 Heading    Number of lines: n2
Line 1
Line 2
...
Line n2
```

where certain sections of the file start with a header line that specifies how many lines are in that section. Each section heading has a different name.

I have written a regular expression that will match the header line based on the header name the user searches for each section, parse it, and then return the number n1/n2/etc that tells me how many lines are in the section. I have been trying to use a for-in loop to read through each line until a counter reaches n1, but it hasn't worked out so far.

Here's my question: how do I return just a certain number of lines following a matched line when that number is given in the match and different for each section? I'm new to programming, and I appreciate any help.

EDIT: Okay, here's the relevant code that I have so far:

```
import re
print
fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
toolname = raw_input("Enter toolname: ")

def findcounter(fname, toolname):
        logfile = open(fname, "r")

        pat = 'SUCCESS Number of lines :'
        #headers all have that format
        for line in logfile:
                if toolname in line:
                    if pat in line:
                            s=line

        pattern = re.compile(r"""(?P<name>.*?)     #starting name
                             \s*SUCCESS        #whitespace and success
                             \s*Number\s*of\s*lines  #whitespace and strings
                             \s*\:\s*(?P<n1>.*)""",re.VERBOSE)
        match = pattern.match(s)
        name = match.group("name")
        n1 = int(match.group("n1"))
        #after matching line, I attempt to loop through the next n1 lines
        lcount = 0
        for line in logfile:
             if line == match:
                    while lcount <= n1:
                                match.append(line)
                                lcount += 1
                                return result
```

The file itself is pretty long, and there are lots of irrelevant lines interspersed between the sections I'm interested in. What I'm not too sure about is how to specify printing the lines directly after a matched line.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code that you have so far? Please read [this](/) page and then update your question.

Comment: I know this is old as f***, but you saved my life.
That int(match.group("n1"))... <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# f is a file object
# n1 is how many lines to read
lines = [f.readline() for i in range(n1)]
```

Comment: But how do I specify only printing the lines directly after the matched header line?

Comment: @Simos: you read the lines from the file one by one. As soon as the current line matches your filter, perform the code I provided. Note that each `readline` from the file moves the file's internal read pointer to the next line

Answer (score 0):

You can put logic like this in a generator:

```
def take(seq, n):
    """ gets n items from a sequence """
    return [next(seq) for i in range(n)]

def getblocks(lines):
    # `it` is a iterator and knows where we are in the list of lines.
    it = iter(lines)
    for line in it:
        try:
            # try to find the header:
            sec, heading, num = line.split()
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            # didnt work, try the next line
            continue

        # we got a header, so take the next lines
        yield take(it, num) 

#test
data = """
Section1 Heading  3
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Maybe some irrelevant lines

Section2 Heading 2
Line 1
Line 2
""".splitlines()

print list(getblocks(data))
```