# find the 3rd line after matched line

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, text-files

I have txt file for searching, and a csv file for referencing. I need to search each item from csv file in txt file. But, I just want to save the third line of the matching line.

The txt file contect is :

```
SCJ 149  NAME ....
 PROGRAM_FILE...
 WTT_FILE...
SCJ 146  NAME...
 PROGRAM_FILE...
 WTT_FILE...
.
.
.
.
SCJ 1522 NAME ....
 PROGRAM_FILE...
 WTT_FILE...
```

The referencing file is :

```
SCJ 1
SCJ 2
SCJ 3
SCJ 4
SCJ 5
.
.
.
.
SCJ 2042
```

So I want to pick each item from referencing file, and match the SCJ XXX code within txt file, but I want the third line information after matching code.

I programmed the code as following:

```
import pandas as pd
aaa = pd.read_csv('refer.csv')
aaa = aaa.as_matrix()
for j in range(len(aaa)):
    with open ('data.txt','r') as root:    
        for i in root:
            if str(aaa[j][0]) + '  NAME' in i:
                lines = [root.readline() for i in range(3)]
```

but it shows an error `Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You are duplicating your variable: `for i in root:` & `... for i in range(3)]`

Comment: @Alexander I followed this answer:' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443392/python-how-to-grab-certain-number-of-lines-after-match'